# A word for passing through a tollgate, turnpike, etc

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a noun that describes a car passing through a tollgate; it's this event I'm trying to name. A person going through a turnpike might be similar, I guess. Possible use of word would be for example:

- 500 cars passed through this tollgate today.

  - There were 500 "**x**"s today from this tollgate.
  - There were 500 car "**x**"s today from this tollgate.

*Passage* was the first word I thought of, but google doesn't seem to agree (I'm still not sure though).

**Clarification:** It doesn't have to be a tollgate (which guards the boundaries of a highway). Let's say, for example, a person is standing next to a road and counting the number of cars that pass. At the end of the day, he says "500 cars passed today; there were 500 **x**'s".

Comment: I don't know if there is an overlap between the terms one might use to describe the tollgate/turnpike situation and the cars-passing-by-a-certain-point situation.  In the tollgate sentences, I would expect the first to be "tolls" or, less repetitively, "collections".  The word "from" seems like it would much more likely be "through", considering the probable form of "X".  I took a look at Wikipedia's articles on [Traffic Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_flow) and [Traffic Counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_count), but nothing jumped out at me.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Transits" perhaps. It's a fairly obscure word but I think it means what you're looking for.

Comment: Or 'transitions'

Answer (score 1):

You may use **entries** or **exits**

**Edit 1**:
*Pass* may also denote "the act of passing" as a "noun".  You may use **pass**.

Comment: I'm not sure - to me, the word "entry" implies that some object entered some place and *stayed* there. The cars do not stay in the gate, they pass through it.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, we can enter / exit  the highway / road through the tollgate. Consider OP's sentence " ...from this tollgate"

Comment: @Mustafa Please see my update.

Comment: why dont you use **passage**? Well, it may sound a little weird. But, if the context is clear, then, "passage of cars" looks fine I would say. **There were 500 passages through this road.**